# replace string in text file in R

Tags: r

If I read in a text file within R and I want to replace a string in that text file based on some pattern. For example create a function call it: replace(query, pattern, param) which basically search through the entire query and replace any occurrences of pattern to param. 
For example,

#### Input FILE

```
select * FROM 
from Meds_EDW
 WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('pattern', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Then there will be a function in R which reads this input file and replace the 'pattern' to a date.

I want to run some kind of loop which will run this sql input file for multiple dates.

Comment: I seem to be missing the question here. Are you just looking for `gsub`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample code, or at very least some concrete examples of your desired input and output. As it stands this is not really a programming question. Also, have look at `?gsub`.

Comment: Hi bdemarest and MrFlick, gsub was the function I was looking for. Thanks!
query<-readChar('Input.txt',file.info('Input.txt')$size)
gsub('PARAM_DATE','01/01/2011',query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for `sprintf(...)`

```
template <- "select * FROM from Meds_EDW WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('%s', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
query <- sprintf(template, "01/01/2014")
query
# [1] "select * FROM from Meds_EDW WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"

dates   <- c("01/01/2014","02/01/2014","03/01/2014")
for (date in dates) print(sprintf(template,date))
# [1] "select * FROM from Meds_EDW WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
# [1] "select * FROM from Meds_EDW WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('02/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
# [1] "select * FROM from Meds_EDW WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('03/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
```

Note the use of `%s` as a placeholder for a string. See the documentation for other options.

If you're already using `sqldf` (which loads `gsubfn`), then this will work as well:

```
library(sqldf)
template <- "select * FROM from Meds_EDW WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('$date.var', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
date.var <- "01/01/2014"
fn$identity(template)
# [1] "select * FROM from Meds_EDW WHERE Meds_EDW.Medication_Start_Date < to_date('01/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
```